# Как отсортировать объект users по параметру "age" и вывести в виде таблицы используя только javascript и css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
let users = [

    {"name":"Григорий", "surname":"Андреев", "age": 32},
    {"name":"Иван", "surname":"Иванов", "age": 23},
    {"name":"Александр", "surname":"Смирнов", "age": 27}

];
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно таким образом:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        let users = [
            {"name":"Григорий", "surname":"Андреев", "age": 32},
            {"name":"Иван", "surname":"Иванов", "age": 23},
            {"name":"Александр", "surname":"Смирнов", "age": 27}
        ];
        let table = document.getElementById('table');
        
        users.sort(compareAge);
        users.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
            let tr = '<tr>' + '<td>'+item.name+'</td>' + '<td>'+item.surname+'</td>' + '<td>'+item.age+'</td>' +'</tr>';
            table.querySelector('tbody').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',tr);
        });
    });

    function compareAge(personA, personB) {
        return personA.age - personB.age;
    }
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Имя</th>
            <th>Фамилия</th>
            <th>Возраст</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Если нужно только JS, самое быстрое решение без создания узлов:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<table id="table">\n' +
            '    <thead>\n' +
            '        <tr>\n' +
            '            <th>Имя</th>\n' +
            '            <th>Фамилия</th>\n' +
            '            <th>Возраст</th>\n' +
            '        </tr>\n' +
            '    </thead>\n' +
            '    <tbody>\n' +
            '    </tbody>\n' +
            '</table>');

        let users = [
            {"name":"Григорий", "surname":"Андреев", "age": 32},
            {"name":"Иван", "surname":"Иванов", "age": 23},
            {"name":"Александр", "surname":"Смирнов", "age": 27}
        ];
        let table = document.getElementById('table');
        
        users.sort(compareAge);
        users.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
            let tr = '<tr>' + '<td>'+item.name+'</td>' + '<td>'+item.surname+'</td>' + '<td>'+item.age+'</td>' +'</tr>';
            table.querySelector('tbody').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',tr);
        });
    });

    function compareAge(personA, personB) {
        return personA.age - personB.age;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать это без hml т.е. как будто в index.html у нас вообще ничего нет кроме <head> и <body> условно? Т.е. нет заранее созданной таблицы с id="table" которую мы можем найти через getElementById.

Comment: @Михаил, создать таблицу js'ом

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, можно через создание новых узлов "по красивому" через `document.createElement('table')`...